# LDAP passport strategy for Hyperledegr composer

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, ldap, passport.js, hyperledger-composer

I have been trying to use LDAP passport strategy for authentication in hyperledger composer rest server. I am using below configuration for ldap passport:

```
export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "ldap": {
      "provider":"ldap",
      "authScheme":"ldap",
      "module":"passport-ldapauth",
      "authPath":"/auth/ldap",
      "successRedirect":"/",
      "failureRedirect":"/",
      "server":"{  
         "url":"ldap://localhost:389",
         "bindOn":"cn=admin,dc=example, dc=com",
         "bindCredentials":"*****",
         "searchBase":"ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com",
      }"
  }
}'
```

While starting composer-rest-server with authentication its showing error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 210
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Promise.then (/home/mfgteg/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/server.js:127:34)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: You have a comma (,) at the end of the searchBase line - maybe that is the problem.

Comment: You should provide a callback url too for default redirecting after authentication.

Comment: Just seen that you have 'bindOn' when it should be `bindDN` (Distinguished Name)

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct format. Thanks to a link I found on [IBM site](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/configuring-tokenbased-ldap-authentication-with-loopback-io-2/.)

I used the following configuration :

```
    export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "ldap": {
      "provider": "ldap",
      "authScheme": "ldap",
      "module": "passport-ldapauth",
      "authPath": "/auth/ldap",
      "successRedirect": "/",
      "failureRedirect": "/",
      "server": {  
         "url": "ldap://localhost:389",
         "bindDn": "cn=admin,dc=example, dc=com",
         "bindCredentials": "*****",
         "searchBase": "ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
      }
  }
}'
```

However I am yet to figure out what to mention in "callbackURL".

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable provided below. Just change the `successRedirect` and `credentials` as per your configuration. Also in case you are running Client application on some other machine, you may need to change the `localhost` in `url` to your machine IP address.

Note : I have tested this with open LDAP configured.

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "ldap": {
   "provider": "ldap",
   "authScheme": "ldap",
   "module": "passport-ldapauth",
   "authPath": "/auth/ldap",
   "successRedirect": "Where you want to redirect",
   "failureRedirect": "/ldap",
   "session": true,
   "json": true,
   "LdapAttributeForLogin": "cn",
   "LdapAttributeForUsername": "cn",
    "server": {
    "url": "ldap://localhost:389",
    "bindDN": "cn=admin,dc=hsc,dc=com",
    "bindCredentials": "xxxxx", 
    "searchBase": "ou=users,dc=hsc,dc=com",
    "searchFilter": "(cn={{username}})"
  }
}
}'
```